# How do I use opencl on blender, libreoffice, davinci but unfortunately with AMD graphics?

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I want to use [opencl](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) on blender, libreoffice, and davinci but my AMD GPU prevents success.

I've used Linux since 1999 (slackware) and compiled kernels back then. But now at 2019 owning an AMD graphics card and I am unable to use opencl in any application at all.

On Arch Linux there's a package on aur repository with the name opencl-amd which, if installed, you can actually  use opencl without installing the proprietary driver that brings so many problems.

My 18.04.3 installation that I had the amdgpu-pro driver installed just could not start xorg after updates.  I can't find a way and installing the amdgpu-pro driver is not a choice.  You help would be appreciated.

This is pretty important: davinci will not launch without opencl, blender and libreoffice will run faster with opencl and do more complex stuff. It is needed.

Comment: See https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/darktable_and_opencl_amd.html

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://linuxconfig.org/install-opencl-for-the-amdgpu-open-source-drivers-on-debian-and-ubuntu) (first result when I google "amd opencl linux")? Quote: "You can install just the OpenCL parts of the AMDGPU-PRO drivers on your Debian or Ubuntu system using the packages provided by AMD."

Comment: Installing just the part of the amdgpu-pro driver that has to do with opencl isn't an option on ubuntu releases after 18.04.3 and i don't know if its still possible in 18.04.3 . This is not good , i guess most of the ubuntu users must either have an nvidia gpu or they are gamers and not professionals . This is very frustrating

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose the problem. We need to see:
1) how was amdgpu pro deb installed exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly easy !
Download the amdgpu-pro driver

tar xf amdgpu-pro-19.30-855429-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz

Rename the folder
$ mv amdgpu-pro-19.30-855429-ubuntu-18.04 amdgpu-pro-repo

Move your repository to /opt
$ sudo mv amdgpu-pro-repo /opt

Make the repo
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-pro.list

Content:
deb file:/opt/amdgpu-pro-repo /

update and allow insecure repositories security risks
$ sudo apt update --allow-insecure-repositories

Install legacy opencl driver. 
$ sudo apt install clinfo-amdgpu-pro opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd

that's it !
works for me every time and in any ubuntu derivative distro and even debian

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to diagnose the problem. We need to see:

- Motherboard chipset, PCIe 2.0 or 3.0?
- What video card do you have?
- How was amdgpu pro deb installed exactly
- Logfiles
- Any additional X server config in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
- what driver is actually assigned to your card?

  $ lspci -k -nn -s 01:00.0 
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X] [1002:67df] (rev ef)
          Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Radeon RX 570 Gaming 4G [1458:22f7]
          Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
          Kernel modules: amdgpu

As a first line of sanity. Blacklist the radeon kernel module and increase logging on the amdgpu module by appending `amdgpu.dc_log=1` to your grub cmdline.

You may have to force DRI3 for it to run. You can accomplish that by creating the following file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf

Section "Module"
    Load "dri3"
    Load "glamoregl"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "AMD"
  Driver "amdgpu"
  Option "Accel" "on"
  Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
  Option "TearFree" "auto"
  Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I got OpenCL to work with my AMD card -- and saw the option in Blender -- with these instructions:
https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html#ubuntu-support---installing-from-a-debian-repository
and scroll down to section: **Performing an OpenCL-only Installation of ROCm** .
Be sure to update your system and add the repository.

I did not install the amdgpu-pro drivers because I read negative comments on other forums. The installation was successful, so pro was not needed. I did the OpenCL-driver only because I did not need the entire package of their project.

With that driver, it seemed like there were more crashes with watching videos and regular use, so I've uninstalled it, and will install again when I want to use Blender. I am not sure what the crash causes were due to, but swapping back to regular amd driver seems to have reduced crash frequency with regular use.

This worked for me with Blender. However, I did not try with LibreOffice or DaVinci.